# How to use 过 and 了?

Tags: difference

How to use 过 and 了? What is the difference between them?

Are my sentences correct?

今天我学习了汉语。Today I studied Chinese. 
我学习过汉语。 I have studied Chinese.
我学习了三个月中文。 I studied Chinese for three months.
我汉语学习了三个月了。 I have been studying Chinese for three months.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah your sentences are pretty good.

了 - indicates change in state.

过 - indicates something has been done before.

For instance:

看完了 = I finished reading it
看过 = I've read that before

Seems like you have a pretty good grasp already from your sentences.

Answer (score 4):

了 is a past tense indicator, working as "-ed" suffix in English. 了 could either be put right after the verb or at the end of the sentence.

过 is a perfect tense indicator, working as "have + V-ed" in English. 过 could either be put right after the verb or at the end of the sentence.